# How to use entry_timeout and attr_timeout in FUSE/OSXFUSE low-level API?

Tags: filesystems, fuse, macfuse

Is there any way to safely use non-zero timeouts in non-readonly filesystems? I cannot seem to find one. A couple of counter-examples:

Example One (non-zero negative entry timeout):

1. An application calls stat() and gets ENOENT;
2. calls create();
3. calls stat(), expecting success, but gets ENOENT instead because of negative entry timeout, so it concludes the FS is broken/inconsistent/etc.

Example Two (non-zero attr timeout):

1. An application calls utimes();
2. calls stat(), but gets stale values and concludes the FS is broken/inconsistent/etc.

I cannot come up with a counterexample for a positive entry timeout - it seems that even if lookup() returns some stale inode, the filesystem still can return ENOENT for the later getattr() call.

But what about the above 2 examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for reference, the same question was posted on the [FUSE mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.fuse.devel/13628/focus=13628).

Here's the [answer from Kyle Lippincott](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.fuse.devel/13629) on why non-zero timeouts work:

> If the create() goes through the kernel, it invalidates the negative
>   entry timeout.  If the create happens externally, then the timeout
>   still holds.

Quoting Goswin von Brederlow on when non-zero timeouts are a problem:

> Caching only works correctly if you implement a disk based filesystem,
>   one where only the fuse process can alter metadata and all access goes
>   only through fuse. Any overlay filesystem where something can change
>   the underlying filesystem without going through fuse can run into
>   inconsistencies.

So if you're e.g. building a network file system that allows multiple hosts to change the data you might get problems with non-zero timeouts.